# How should width be set for a bar in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

I'm using python 2, and the following code is just using some example data, my actual data can be of varying lengths and might not be minutely.

```
  import numpy as np
  import datetime  
  import matplotlib
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

  fig, ax = plt.subplots()  

  x_values = [datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 8, 11, 16), 
    datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 8, 11, 17), 
    datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 8, 11, 18), 
    datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 8, 11, 19), 
    datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 8, 11, 20), 
    datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 8, 11, 21), 
    datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 8, 11, 22), 
    datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 8, 11, 23), 
    datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 8, 11, 24), 
    datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 8, 11, 25), 
    datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 8, 11, 26), 
    datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 8, 11, 27), 
    datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 8, 11, 28), 
    datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 8, 11, 29), 
    datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 8, 11, 30), 
    datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 8, 11, 31)]
  y_values = [1392.1017964071857,
    1392.2814371257484,
    1392.37125748503,
    1227.6802721088436,
    1083.1,
    1317.0461538461539,
    1393.059880239521,
    1393.4011976047905,
    1393.491017964072,
    1393.8502994011976,
    1318.3461538461538,
    1229.4965986394557,
    1394.2095808383233,
    1394.3892215568862,
    1394.6586826347304,
    1394.688622754491]

  rects1 = ax.bar(x_values, y_values)
  fig.tight_layout()
  plt.show()
```

How am I supposed to set the width of the bars automatically?  As it is I get the following:

[image: no width set[1]]

If I set the width to 0.0006 then it looks good for the example data:

[image: width manually set to 0.0006[2]]

from which I've worked out that matplotlib is measuring the x axis in days (since 0.0007 days is almost exactly 1 minute, which matches my time intervals, and 0.0006 gives the gaps between bars) but that's no good if I get hourly values or seconds, or weeks, etc.  Surely there's an option for handling this automatically?

Comment: What would be the expected outcome for non-equally spaced data?

Comment: Dunno what would be expected as I can't work it out from the docs.  If I had to pick a default right now on the spur of the moment I'd say the smallest any individual one of them would have to be.

Comment: OK, here's a follow up question setting aside whether it can be done automatically - when using datetimes, is the unit for the axis always going to be days?  If so, I can use my own formula to work out sizes.  If not, how can I find out what the unit is?

Comment: The answer to that is yes - they're always days.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want the bar width to be no larger than the difference between any successive datetimes, you can calculate that number and supply it to the bar's `width` argument.

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates 

width = np.min(np.diff(mdates.date2num(x_values)))
ax.bar(x_values, y_values, width=width, ec="k")
```

[image]

Comment: So the x-axis is using matplotlib.dates.date2num(d) on the dates, which returns a number of days as a float, so the unit is always days.  Awesome, thanks!

Comment: This should be a default behaviour! Thanks!

Comment: I'd give this answer 10 points if I could.