# Plotting Time Series with Matplotlib: Using datetime.datetime() works but datetime.datetime.strptime(str, format) does not

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wish to plot a some data in a bar graph using matplotlib. The x-values of the plot should be datetime.datetime objects so that matplotlib can use them. If I generate the time values with the following method it works:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

x = [datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 1, 10, 0),
     datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 4, 9, 0),
     datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 5, 9, 0)]
y = [4, 9, 2]

ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.bar(x, y, width=10)
ax.xaxis_date()
plt.show()
```

Yielding this plot:

[image: Text](https://stackoverflow.com/image.jpg)[enter image description here]

However if I use the following method it does not work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

dates = ["2020-05-11 18:25:37","2020-05-11 18:25:40","2020-05-11 18:25:43",
         "2020-05-11 18:25:46","2020-05-11 18:25:49"]
X = []
for date in dates:
    X.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

Y = [1, 3, 4, 6, 4]


ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.bar(X, Y, width=10)
ax.xaxis_date()
plt.show()
```

Yielding this abomination:

[image]

I am obviously missing something here but it appears to me that the results should be the same for:

```
datetime.datetime(2010, 12 ,1 ,10, 0)
datetime.datetime.strptime('2010-12-01 10:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: To begin with, all the data specified are '2020-05-11', so the X-axis is based on the day, so there is only one bar graph.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I see what you mean. Do you know of a way to alter the x-axis such that the resolution is in seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by a datetime width for matplotlib having to be expressed in units of 1 day. So if width = 1, a bar width is equal to a day on the x-axis.

This was resolved by making the width be equal to a percentage of a day appropriate for the time scale used, in this case 3 seconds. For example, if you want the bar width to occupy 3 seconds on the x-axis make the width equal to 3 seconds as a percentage of a whole day,

```
#NB: There are 86400 seconds in a day and I want a width of 3 seconds. 
ax.plot(width = (1/(86400))*3)
```

If you wish for the bars to not touch you should reduce the width of the bars to less than the interval between timestamps as plotted on the x-axis. Further if you wish to dyamically determine the minimum interval between timestamps please look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53209200/how-should-width-be-set-for-a-bar-in-matplotlib).

Answer (score 0):

You can use date2num to convert the dates to matplotlib format.

Plot the dates and values using [plot_date](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=plot_date#matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date):

```
X = matplotlib.dates.date2num(X)
matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date(X,Y)
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

or you can use like this

```
ax.plot_date(X, Y)
```

Comment: Thank you for your respons, I'm unsure as to whether I can use plot_date() to create a bar graph.

Answer (score 0):

The bar graph cannot be displayed due to an error, while the line graph shows the x-axis in minutes:seconds. I'm sorry I can't help you.

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import matplotlib.dates as mdates
 import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

 fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,4.5))
 ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

 dates = ["2020-05-11 18:25:37","2020-05-11 18:25:40","2020-05-11 18:25:43",
     "2020-05-11 18:25:46","2020-05-11 18:25:49"]

 Y = [1, 3, 4, 6, 4]
 df = pd.DataFrame({'Y':Y}, index=pd.to_datetime(dates))

 ax.plot(df.index, df['Y'])

 xloc = mdates.SecondLocator(interval=1)
 xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter("%M:%S")
 ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(xloc)
 ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
 plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks so much for the response. What you said in your comment about the scale of the xaxis only displaying one day was invaluable and pointed me in the right direction. Turns out that the problem was the width value. I wished to plot points for every 3 seconds but the default width is 1 Day, so I had to change the width of a bar to 3 seconds, i.e.  width = (1/(# seconds in a day) * 3).